# javascript date object doesnt return result

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

[image]

i have this calendar table(its bunch of floated divs.. not `<table>`),

my user should be able to click anywhere on row to add new booking. problem is how to calculate the time where he clicked.

so i use:

```
$('day-column').click(function(e){
  var posY = $(this).offset().top;//get offset of click
  var pos=(e.pageY - posY)* 60 * 1000;//convert it into millisec (since 1px=1min)
  var start=8 * 60 * 60 * 1000;//covert starting hour 8:00 into millisec
  var d = new Date();//create date object
  d.setMilliseconds((start+pos));//set obj millisec

  console.log(d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes());//try to extract new hour and time

});
```

Why is this not working ?? am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: And what's the purpose of all this...?

Comment: @gdoron google like calendar. user click on div it open a form with time he clicked on, and after he finish, he can also drag/resize to update time of booking on mysql

Comment: Why don't you just take the position and divide by 60 to determine how many hours. You may need to round the position though.

Comment: thats what im trying to do.. but i dont know how to make time in javascript

Comment: adding your HTML here for the calendar might help us to figure out what you are actually working with.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using : 
http://momentjs.com/

will support on all browsers , simple , and you can have the format option.
which i think you will like.